# Mongoose and MERN: unable to call and route multiple finds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm using react-big-calendar and I want a findById (to manipulate each event for editing and deleting) and a findByUser (for persistence with the database).

**Controllers**

```
const db = require("../models");

module.exports = {
findAll: function(req, res) {
    db.Event
    .find()
    .then(dbModel => {

        res.json(dbModel)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},
findByUser: function(req, res) {
    db.Event
    .find({user: req.params.user})
    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},
findById: function(req, res) {
    db.Event
    .findById(req.params.id)
    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},
create: function(req, res) {
    db.Event
    .create(req.body)
    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
},
update: function(req, res) {
    db.Event
    .findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": req.params.id }, 
        {
            "title": req.body.title,
            "start": req.body.start,
            "end": req.body.end,
            "description": req.body.description
        },
        { new: true }
    )
    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err))
},
remove: function(req, res) {
    db.Event
    .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then(dbModel => dbModel.remove())
    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
}
}
```

**Routes**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const calendarController = require("../../controllers/calendarController");
const passport = require("passport");

router.route("/")
  .get(calendarController.findAll)
  .post(calendarController.create);

router.route("/:user")
  .get(calendarController.findByUser);

router.route("/:id")
  .get(calendarController.findById)
  .put(calendarController.update)
  .delete(calendarController.remove);


module.exports = router;
```

At this point, the findById is returning an empty array. If I swap the order of the user route and the id route, it findById then works but the user then returns a null. What's happening here? Can I call a document by the ID and user Id separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here your both the routes `/:user` and `/:id` cannot make the difference... Which ever finds first, executes first and other will be overriding

There is only way to get out of this is to change the name of the routes

```
router.route("/user/:user")  // change the route name here
  .get(calendarController.findByUser);

router.route("/:id")
  .get(calendarController.findById)
  .put(calendarController.update)
  .delete(calendarController.remove);
```